# Select all except duplicate columns unless the length of the column's string is longest

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, select

I have a table with the following columns:

strWord, strWordType, strWordDescription

I'd like to be able to select all of the rows except the ones where there is a duplicate strWordDescription. In the case of duplicates, I only want to return the rows where strWord has the longest length. This should only take effect if strWordType is the same.

Notes: There are no duplicate rows of strWords/strWordType combinations only duplicate strWordDescriptions for specific strWordTypes. I would like to avoid using `Distinct`.

**Example:** *myTable*

```
  strWord |    strWordType  |   strWordDescription |

  blue         2012               This is a color
  blue         2014               This is a color
  green        2012               This is a color
  ham          2014               This is a food
  chicken      2014               This is a food
```

**Expected Results:**

```
   strWord  |   strWordType   | strWordDescription

   green        2012            This is a color
   blue         2014            This is a color
   chicken      2014            This is a food
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: show sample data and expected result

Comment: okay.. feel free to help yourself

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Added an example

Comment: "In the case of duplicates, I only want to return the rows where strWord has the longest length. This should only take effect if strWordType is the same." In your example the blues have a different strWordType, yet one is eliminated. How does that add up?

Comment: @stickyBit The blue 2012 is deleted because the green 2012 has a longer length, the strWordType is the same, and the strWordDescription is the same. The strWord/strWordType combination will never be a duplicate.

Comment: Ah, missed that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it   -

```
SELECT MAX(mt.strWord),
       mt.strWordType,
       mt.strWordDescription


FROM myTable mt
GROUP BY mt.strWordType, mt.strWordDescription
ORDER BY MAX(mt.strWord)
```

Comment: You can select it as the accepted answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @CompSciFly . . . I don't see how `max()` has anything to do with the longest word, so I don't see how this solves your problem.  If you want the last word alphabetically, then you should ask another question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Using max in SQL Server allows us to group by strWordType and strWordDescription and still select strWord as well. The order by is what's ordering by the length of strWord. This does exactly as expected.

Comment: @CompSciFly . . . This doesn't answer the question that you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . a correlated subquery comes to mind:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.strword = (select top (1) t2.strword
                   from t t2
                   where t2.description = t.description and
                         t2.strWordType = t.strWordType
                   order by len(t2.strword) desc
                  );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although, this one was about 10x slower performance wise, so I will go with the other.

Comment: @CompSciFly . . . Interesting.  How does the performance compare with an index on `(description, strWordType, strword)`?

Comment: The subquery causes a cost of 89%

Comment: This method should be the fastest method with an index on `(description, strWordType, strword)`.

Comment: we cannot index on strWord because we are not trying to include all of those. Indexing on description and wordType works because we are wanting to disclude the entries with the same description and wordType but where there's a strWord that's longer.